# Firefox Driver in Selenium 2 work too slow when is set the proxy settings

Tags: proxy, selenium-webdriver

I have problems with the firefox driver when I set the proxy settings. The settings is properly settled, but is working to slow and the firefox driver can't continue the program. My purpose is to open google then type some search criteria, to submit this criteria and to open one of the result pages that is show. Everything is good when I don't use the proxy. Here is my code for proxy:

```
       FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
       profile.setPreference("network.proxy.type", 1);
       profile.setPreference("network.proxy.http","some Proxy");
       profile.setPreference("network.proxy.http_port", port); 
       driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

Comment: And if you use the proxy settings manually in your Firefox, the browsing is smooth, too?

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below one:

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();          
profile.setPreference("network.proxy.type", ProxyType.AUTODETECT.ordinal());    
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```